# How to use object id that give reference in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reference, schema

There is no another error but I want to know just one thing.How to use that give reference in User schema object _id it means location_id how to use when I add new User.

User Schema :

```
    var userSchema = Mongoose.Schema({ 

        name:{type: String,require:true},
        surname: {type: String,require:true},
        tel: {type: String,require:true},
        age: {type: String,require:true},
        mevki_id: {type: String,require:true},
        location_id: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'locations' }
});
```

Location schema:

```
var LocationSchema = Mongoose.Schema ({         


    il: {type: String, require:true},

    ilce: {type:String, require:true}          

});
```

UserController --  I add user here

```
this.createUser = function(req, res) {

    var la=new Location({il:'istanbul',ilce:'camlica',location_id:la._id}).save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
    });

    var user = new User({
        name:'akif',surname:'demirezen',tel:'544525',age:'45',mevki_id:'2',

    }).save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(job));
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. For example, the `require` property should be `required`.

Other problem is that you are setting the location_id value of la with a reference to la, that at that time has not been yet assigned a value.

Mongo will automatically create a field called _id: ObjectId on all your objects. Try this:

```
this.createUser = function(req, res) {

  var la = new Location({
    il:'istanbul',
    ilce:'camlica',
  }).save(function (err, location) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    var user = new User({
      name:'akif',
      surname:'demirezen',
      tel:'544525',
      age:'45',
      mevki_id:'2',
      location_id: location._id
    }).save(function (err, user) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      // Warning: AFAIK job does not exist, should it be user?
      res.send(JSON.stringify(job));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I really thnk u ztrange  but  I guess could be this  res.send(JSON.stringify(user));